# SharePoint: Do not see any Filter Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

In the official Office 2007 site there are numerous reference to Filter Web Parts. 
When I try to add one of them, the Web Part list in my Sharepoint doesn't show any Filter Web Parts.

Please post if anyone experienced the same and any resolution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

in MOSS activate the Office SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features Feature

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using wss 3.0 ( Windows SharePoint services) and not the MOSS 2007? wss does not have filter web parts.

Answer (score 1):

As Nico said they belong to MOSS Enterprise. They can be added by clicking on the new button in the web-part gallery and select the correct classes, or by uploading the WebPart definition files from %CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\BizAppsSiteTemplates\dwp.

I don't know if this is against the license agreement or not.

Answer (score 1):

So if you are using WSS 3.0 and not MOSS 2007 by now you know why you do not have any filter webparts; to solve the problem you could install some freely available filter webparts: try the [Dropdown Filter Web Part for SharePoint](http://dropdownsharepoint.codeplex.com/) or the [List Item Filter webpart of e-office](http://eoffice.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=List%20Item%20Filter%20webpart&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 0):

Preconfigured Filter webpart are only available in MOSS Enterprise.
However, you can create your own, the framework is there (in fact you can import themin a MOSS Std and it will work).

Answer (score 0):

We are using MOSS 2007 but had to follow JMDs instruction to load them manually.

Thanks to all of you.

This is very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

you can see all available webparts in site settings --> webparts --> click on NEW if you dont see them there you