# Creating a sharepoint 2007 search for a list (results only from that list)?

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

I have been researching this for some time, and have not been able to find a solution.  I would just like to have a search bar that when an ID is entered, the search will return all the list items that have that ID.

I'm sure I am leaving out details (as I am a sharepoint novice), but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to search only for ID, or you want a multiple criteria search? or a full text search on all fields? And most of all, which edition of sharepoint do you run?

Comment: Just for an ID. There will be multiple entries for each ID, and I just want to see a list of those IDs when an ID is entered into the search. I am using SharePoint 2007, WSS, version: 12.0.0.6421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is not search, but filter.

In the view of you library, follow these steps :

1. Put the page in edit mode
2. Add a web part "Text Filter Web Part"
3. Open its tool pane
4. Name the filter, "IDFilter" for example, and validate
5. Still in edit mode, select "Modify shared Web Part" --> "Connections" --> "Send filter values to *name of your library*"
6. Choose the field that holds your ID and click "Finish"

That's it. You can now type the ID in the field, and it will dynamically apply a filter on the ID field.

That said, you should post you future questions on http://SharePoint.stackexchange.com. this is a SharePoint dedicated stackexchange site.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the time Steve.  And will do on the posting location, sorry about that.

Comment: Apparently WSS doesn't have filter web parts? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: According [this answser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/625487/588868), WSS does not provide Filter web parts. Fortunately, in the answer, there are links to alternatives.